# can not Deactivate this device Administrator

Tags: android, device-admin, device-owner

Have an application granted device administration, while trying to uninstall went to device Administrator screen, but the option to Deactivate this device administrator text's visibility is dim and i can not deactivate.

Comment: May you are trying to disable system application permission. Can you please tell me the application name?

Comment: @AlpeshSorathiya thanks for your response, it is solved now.

Answer (score 1):

an app which is provisioned to be be device owner can not be removed as device owner by the user.

i think it make sense.
once the Device Owner application is set, it cannot be unset with the adb dpm command. it can be programmatically done by this code called by owner app itself.

```
DevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwnerApp()
```

or it has to be  factory reset your device.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in terminal.

adb shell dpm remove-active-admin com.your.App.Package/.DevAdminReceiver 0